# RCSI on SQL Server 2008 - how to tell if on

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to be sure that I have enabled RCSI on my SQL Server 2008. Is there a way to display the flags on different features of SQL to tell if they are on or off? I also wasn't sure if running the query to turn the feature on again would hurt anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you run SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES, one of the columns will tell you.

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx